# Concatenate two separate strings from arrays in a for loop

Tags: python, concatenation

Okay so I have two lists, they can be anywhere from just one value long to 20, but they will always have the same amount as eachother.

e.g

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Now my objective is to create a for loop that would go through both lists, and add the corresponding values from each list to each other. So..

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', '5e']
```

Just to give another example.

```
names = ['john', 'harry', 'joe']
IDs = ['100', '200', '300']

output: ['john100', 'harry200', 'joe300']
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `join`:

```
[''.join(p) for p in zip(alphabet, numbers)]
# ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']
```

As for the second example:

```
[''.join(p) for p in zip(names, IDs)]
# ['john100', 'harry200', 'joe300']
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Psidom one-liner solution you could just use `zip()`:

```
>>>[i+j for i, j in zip(alphabet, numbers)]
>>>['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']
```

Or if you perfef to use a regular for loop:

```
res = []
for i, j in zip(alphabet, numbers):
    res.append(i+j)
```

You could also make this more general, and put it in a function:

```
# method one
def concancate_elements(list1, list2):
    return [i+j, for i, j in zip(alphabet, numbers)]

# method two
def concancate_elements(list1, list2):
    res = []
    for i, j in zip(alphabet, numbers):
        res.append(i+j)
    return res
```